# Converting a Page to a User Control

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls, user-interface

If we want to convert a Page to user control then we should also do the following:

“If you aren’t using the code-behind model, make sure you still include a class name in the Control directive by supplying the ClassName attribute. This way, the web page that consumes the control can be strongly typed, which allows it to access properties and methods you’ve added to the control..”

I’m not sure I understand the above quote:

Namely, if we  don’t use code behind class, then ascx class will derive directly from UserControl class! 
Thus if we don’t use code behind class, then there won’t be any methods or properties added to a control, so why would web page have problems accessing any of user control’s properties and methods? So why would we need to include a class name in Control directive?

thanx

Answer (score 2):

I think I should clarify how the compilation model works. First of all, you can write everything (including C# code) in a single `.ascx` file and inherit from whatever class you want to (that ultimately inherits from `UserControl`) by specifying `Inherits` attribute (or you might want to omit it) and without a `ClassName` attribute. If you do this, you can still access the properties from the `.aspx` file that uses this control. The thing is, you can't use the class in the codebehind file of `.aspx` page (if it has one) directly. By specifying the `ClassName`, if you are using the Website project model of Visual Studio, you can access it from the `.aspx.cs` file too. Note that this would not work in Web application project model as every `.cs` file will be compiled ahead of the time (prior to the `.ascx` file). In that case, even `ClassName` attribute wouldn't help much.

In any case, strictly none of the attributes are necessary. You can always use the properties defined anywhere in `.ascx` or `.ascx.cs` file included in a page in the `.aspx` file (but *not* always `.aspx.cs` file).

**Edit to address the update to the question:**

A) From your source code, it seems you are using the Website model here. Note that I mentioned you cannot use the *class* directly. I agree this statement might have been a little misleading. What I wanted to note is that without a `ClassName`, ASP.NET will choose a name for your user control class but that name is not guaranteed. While you *can* use the generated name, it's not recommended at all. You should treat it pretty much like an anonymous type where you can use an instance but cannot mention a name. In your example, you are basically referencing an instance (which is constructed on the `.aspx` markup), not the *class*, which is OK.

B) What you are saying is correct. Whatever you declare in `ascx.cs` in a Web application will be visible to `.aspx.cs` and `.aspx`. What I was talking about is properties that you declare in `.ascx` in a `<script runat="server">` tag. Those will not be visible to `.aspx.cs` since it's compiled beforehand.

C) ASP.NET will generate the class defined by the `ClassName` attribute in the `ASP` namespace. You should use `ASP.Some_Name` instead. There is one thing I forgot to mention: in this case, you should somehow reference the `.ascx` in the `.aspx` markup; either with a `Reference` directive (`<%@ Reference Control="MyControl.ascx" %>`) directive or with a `Register` directive (`<%@ Register TagPrefix="abc" TagName="xyz" Src="MyControl.ascx" %>`). This will ensure that the ASP.NET build engine puts the generated `.ascx` class in the same assembly as `.aspx` page.

Answer (score 1):

> if we don’t use code behind class,
>   then there won’t be any methods or
>   properties added to a control, so why
>   would web page have problems accessing
>   any of user control’s properties and
>   methods? So why would we need to
>   include a class name in Control
>   directive

1. You can embed any code behind code in your .ascx/.aspx file, in new asp.net mvc model, there won't be any code behind by default. I think code behind is optional, it's just a nice way to separate one class into two pieces. Partial class is used in code behind.
2. Even if you don't use code behind class, you can still inherited properties from base control. Then by declaring a class, you will be able to access those properties too.